# On a QO breaker, how do I distinguish GFCI from overcurrent trip?

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci

I have a 1-pole Square D "QO" type 1-pole, 20A GFCI breaker (not AFCI).  Plugged into it are:

- Twenty-five CFL lights averaging ~15W each, so 375W nominal
- A 1500W-nominal heater-fan, though, I suspect with the 100' of #14 extension cord, probably running a bit shy of 1500W

If the heater is on, and I plug in the lights, I get a breaker trip.  Often I get a breaker trip *just with the lights*.  I have tried splitting up and powering only sections of lights, with varying and inconclusive results.

It's not unheard of for CFLs to have a pretty serious inrush current, but I am mystified.

I really need to know whether this is a GFCI trip, or an overcurrent trip. The QO breaker has no lights whatsoever.  Can I get the breaker to tell me somehow?  Or should I dump this and go with GFCI receptacles?

Comment: Have you tried timing the trip yet? (i.e. from energization/reset to trip with a known faulty load placed on the breaker)

Comment: Have you measured the inrush current?

Comment: I would use an amp clamp to see what the inrush is , my least expensive clamp has a inrush or peak hold so I can see what the max is on a 20 amp it should not trip under ~32a  in under a second. I have not had issues in the past with cfl’s (harmonics causing this issue) but I have with larger ballasted fixtures.

Comment: If there is another gfci breaker in the panel I would swap the two. If the problem persists I would temporarily connect to regular breaker, and temporarily connect through a gfci receptacle floating in the panel.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The trip is instant.  It first started doing it when I unscrewed a 30W CFL (really big one) with the power on.  The moment the bulb broke contact, the breaker tripped, and continued tripping ever since, even after I removed the light fixture and capped off wires.  It's a mystery!

Comment: Can you get access to a *leakage clampmeter*? (Ordinary clampmeters tend to have poor low-end sensitivity, so there are dedicated units for measuring leakage current)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Not at this location, unfortunately.  In this question I'm hoping to get the QO breaker to *tell me* what kind of trip it is; noting that the dual-function AFCI+GFCI+breakers [have a "secret handshake" way](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/170057/47125) of divining this info.

Comment: Honestly, if the breaker won't tell me, my next step will be to fit a GFCI recep on one of several other unused 20A plain breakers already installed in the box (3 total circuits, 16 spaces, 8 spaces populated; somebody was one of us :) While a poor stone for this bird, it'll kill several other birds.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer. (Huh... "system generated" looking boilerplate text for a @Harper-ReinstateMonica question... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Older Square D breakers

Square D does not provide any means to distinguish type/reason of trip.

### Newer Square D breakers (date code 1130 and newer)

These breakers (at this writing) have white or purple TEST buttons.

The "Time Saver" (heh) diagnostics provide a method for the breaker to tell you the cause of the last trip.

[Link](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/43/43a955a6-2154-4899-9aee-a70a4c2308c3.pdf).... [link](https://www.se.com/us/en/download/document/0700HO1402/).

Generally the procedure is to turn the breaker off, hold down TEST, turn the breaker back on *continuing to hold down TEST*, and time the number of seconds until the breaker trips again.   The amount of delay (if any) reveals the trip cause - ground fault, arc fault, or overcurrent.

Note that Square D arc fault breakers have weak ground fault detection (for the purpose of detecting hot-ground and neutral-ground parallel *arc faults*) — so they *can* in fact trip on a ground fault indication.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, no, there is no way to differentiate the reason for the trip on a basic GFCI circuit breaker (regardless of the make). There is one trip mechanism and indicator, the only thing added to a GFCI breaker is an additional sensor system operating that trip mechanism.

Comment: That is not true for some makes; they have LEDs to indicate trip function.  .  I am looking for an answer for QO.